# how to deal concurrency write request in redis when it be used in user registration

Tags: .net, concurrency, redis, servicestack

I got a problem when i want to use redis in my registration module.
It's a asp.net web site, not MVC.
Users could registrated in my website after they submit their email and mobile phone number.
My application would validate is the new user unique .The validate pipeline validate data in SQL server, if there are a lot of concurrency registration actions, it would insert two same data to the SQL,to resolve this problem, i use redis to cache the registration actions.
when the registration action start, the first step,we check the redis and  insert it to  the redis if the request not exist in the redis, if there is a same request , return false.
I use the ServiceStack.Redis, it's a redis client for .net.
My problem is :
If two same request operate the redis, we define they are A and B. A find it doesn't exist the same request, then B find it doesn't exist the same request too, then A try to set the value in redis,but B try the same things too .Did redis deal this situation?
How to deal the concurrency two write requests in redis?  should i use set or hash to store the user registion data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's your problem right there:

> if there are a lot of concurrency registration actions, it would insert two same data to the SQL

Put unique index on `Email` column (or whatever identifier you use) and you're done. No need to involve redis in that.

In case you still want to use redis, you can leverage its Lua support. That is, you'll have a single function that will check existence of a key and insert it if it's missing (or perform other work associated with registration process).

Redis+Lua documentation: [EVAL command](http://redis.io/commands/eval).

Comment: That means it's prefer to use database to deal the concurrency request.But it's a big application that i have no rights to change the database configuration. And i use the ServiceStack.Redis clien for .net. EVAL command should not be a good choise.

Comment: What, servicestack client doesn't support EVAL? It's the correct way to go, eliminates race conditions.

Comment: sorry, i misunderstanding your advice,i am trying EVAL command now, thank you very much.